# On Pressing of EnterKey on Specific column Of Datagridview open new form

Tags: c#

I have two datagridview 
1. datagridview1
2. datagridview2

i want when i hit the enter key on column 1 on datagridview1 it must open the datagridview2. 
Please help !
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i found

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            testform tf = new testform();

            {
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Selected)
                {
                    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F1")

                    {
                        tf.Show();

                    }



                }
            }
```